# compose lazy gridcells not resolving correctly in a read-only file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, getstream-chat

Required:
androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.GridCells

Found:
androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells

for use with ReactionsPicker... a file from Stream Chat library
ReactionsPicker call is in MessagesActivity
'''
is SelectedMessageReactionsPickerState -> {
val gcells=GridCells.Fixed(5) // I added this. cells is defined in file
ReactionsPicker(
cells= gcells,
modifier = Modifier
.align(Alignment.Center)
.padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
.wrapContentSize(),
shape = ChatTheme.shapes.attachment,
message = selectedMessage,
onMessageAction = { action ->
composerViewModel.performMessageAction(action)
listViewModel.performMessageAction(action)
},
onDismiss = { listViewModel.removeOverlay() }
)
}'''

I have gridcells, but not the right one? pretty sure its in lazy foundation
compose_version = '1.3.0-alpha01'

```
'''    
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.0'

    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    implementation('io.github.raamcosta.compose-destinations:core:1.5.12-beta')
    ksp('io.github.raamcosta.compose-destinations:ksp:1.6.12-beta')
// Paging 3.0
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha15'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.4.2"
    //hilt
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42"
    
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.0'
   
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:$coroutines_version"

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.0.6'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:"



    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    
    //implementation("androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:")
    
    
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.2'

    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    //implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    //implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.2.0"
  
    //Pager
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.23.0"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.13.0"
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    //implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    //implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version"

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    //implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"



    //////STREAM CHAT 
    implementation 'io.getstream:stream-chat-android-compose:5.5.0'
//coil
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:$coil_version"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-gif:$coil_version"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-video:$coil_version"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:$coil_version"

    //implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"

    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
   //implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0-alpha02"
//ROOM
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
    //kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
    //implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"
    
   
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.3"

    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.13.0")
    kapt("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.13.0")
    
    implementation('com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api:1.7.10-1.0.6')
}'''
```

Comment: so I tried to copy their files to migrate to the right gridcells and got stuck on



   `LazyVerticalGrid(modifier = modifier, cells = cells) {
        items(options) { item ->
            key(item.type) {
                itemContent(item)
            }
        }
    } `

It wants columns instead of cells and 

Type mismatch.
Required:
Int
Found:
List<ReactionOptionItemState>

and 'operator fun LazyGridScope.invoke(p2: ReactionOptionItemState): Unit' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary

Comment: So you updated a compose library that had a breaking change and you need to resolve to the new import and function parameters - first 2 lines of your question? If you're using alpha libraries or experimental apis, its bound to happen occassionally.

Comment: Okay, I reported to their support team, will update on solution

Answer (score 1):

The package has been updated from

```
androidx.compose.foundation.lazy
```

to

```
androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid
```

Thus you need to import:

```
androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyVerticalGrid
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error should be resolved with

implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.3.1" in gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [Compose chat tutorial](https://getstream.io/chat/compose/tutorial/), they highly recommend using Compose `1.1.1`. They don't support Compose `1.2.0`~`1.3.0-alpha01` yet, so if you change Compose version to `1.1.1`, it will work well.